# In pool, what happens if the last coloured ball and the white are sunk in the same shot?

Tags: rules, pool

When a person sinks the last coloured ball plus the white ball, while the black ball is remaining, is that game over or does the opposition player gets one shot on the black from the baulk line?

Answer (score 2):

Officially, the game is not over if the 8-ball is not sunk, and the opposition player gets to shoot next. However, this varies significantly between regions, and in many locations the game will end. See [link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eight-ball#Pocketing_the_8_ball):

> If the player knocks the 8 ball off the table then the player loses the game. If the player pockets the 8 ball and commits a foul or pockets it into another pocket than the one designated then the player loses the game
>
> ...
>
> Otherwise (i.e., if the 8 ball is neither pocketed nor knocked off the table) the shooter's turn is simply over, even if a foul occurs. In short, a World Standardized Rules game of eight-ball, like a game of nine-ball, is not over until the "money ball" is no longer on the table.

Comment: Oh.. the asker says "baulk line" which is not part of a pool table

Comment: From Wikipedia: *"Baulk lines may also be drawn on English billiards tables, and even British-style pool tables"*. They're certainly drawn on many of the pool tables I've played. There is something you can fix - talk about the correct game in question, not a related but different game.